# slack rtm api, get usernames from dm channel id and vice-versa

Tags: slack-api

I'm playing around with the [slack rtm api](https://api.slack.com/rtm), and they say that "You can send a message to a private group or direct message channel in the same way, but using a Group ID (C024BE91L) or DM channel ID (D024BE91L)." Is there any way to get from the DM channel ID to the username that you are sending the direct message to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using a workaround to get this, there might be better way but I couldn't find one.

You can make an API call to `im.open` with user id (not username, though it can be retrieved pretty easily), the response will return you the DM channel ID.

This is a quick attempt I did in Python:

```
def get_direct_channel(sc, user_id):
    '''
    Get direct channel id from userid
    sc => slack client
    '''
    direct_message = sc.api_call("im.open", user=user_id)
    channel = direct_message.get("channel")
    if channel:        
        channel_id = channel.get("id")
        if channel_id:
            return channel_id

    return None
```

More info from the [doc](https://api.slack.com/types/im).